# SSHFS files from one server to another

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, filesystems, file-sharing, sshfs

I am trying to find the most secure way to transfer files from one server to another.

I have the following architecture:

[image: Architecture]

Currently I am using the main user `salamis` in order to mount the directories.

The files in the original directory are created through a PHP file manager `elfinder`.

Unfortunately, I am not able to `move`, `rename` or `delete` any file from the mounted directory through PHP. I get permission denied.

1) Is it because I mounted the filesystem using `salamis` instead of `www-data`?

2) Is it secure to mount the filesystem on `Server 2` as `www-data` ? If yes, how can I achieve that? `www-data` does not have a password and I cannot login using `su -m www-data`. I get `authentication failure`.

3) Can you think of a better architecture?

Answer (score 0):

Like you suspected, it's probably an issue of uid/gid mapping. First you'll want to find the uid of `www-data`:

```
$ id www-data
uid=33(www-data) gid=33(www-data) groups=33(www-data)
```

Then you can ask sshfs to map like:

```
$ sshfs -o uid=33,gid=33 <remote> <local>
```

That may solve it.

As far as design goes, just beware that if your ssh connection drops, so goes the mounted file system.  I'm not aware of an easy way to detect it (other than maybe a cron job that detects it). NFS might be more robust if it's an option. I do find sshfs quite handy, though.

Comment: I used `-o reconnect` option to overcome that problem. Where should I put that? `server 2` right?

Comment: Yeah. Cool, didn't know about that option. You should be able to just add these two to your existing options (it's just a comma separated list) and then do the sshfs as your normal user.